# do not include elements into ng-hide on form serialize

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

I gotta a single question, I'm using ng-show and ng-hide to display options on a form based on a select option, however, when I submit my controller looks like this:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

   $scope.submit = function(event) {
       var element = event.currentTarget;
       //so when....
       console.log($(element).serialize());
   };


});
```

So when... I submit, all the elements appears even if the are hidden, I would like to display only those where ng-show is displayed.

Comment: You could use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ng-show` / `ng-hide` use `ng-if`.
`ng-if` will render only those element which satisfy the expression inside `ng-if` attribute condition.

```
ng-if="expression"
```